# trainAutoencoder slows down when using GPU?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to get into deep learning using the neural network library in matlab. A good starting step seems to be training an autoencoder. In that respect, it would be good to see whether I am getting the msot out of my gpu.

In this connection, When I run

```
tic
  autoenc1 = trainAutoencoder(allSets,5,...
   'L2WeightRegularization',0.001,...
   'SparsityRegularization',1,...
   'SparsityProportion',0.2,...
   'DecoderTransferFunction','logsig',...
   'useGPU',true)
 toc
```

I get "Elapsed time is 19.680823 seconds.". 
However, not using the gpu (setting 'useGPU' to false) it only takes 8.272708 seconds. 
 I am puzzled by this, since I am assuming that using the gpu for neural networks will speed things up? Does anyone know of any way to check whether matlab and cuda are properly interfacing, or see how matlab is actually using the resources?

I have cuda 8.1 installed, and am using a GeForce GTX 960M (compute capability 5.0). The matlab version is 2016b.

EDIT: as has been pointed out, there is as of yet no cuda 8.1. What I do have is 8.0, and cudnn 5.1.

Comment: Not all NN-architectures are expected to be faster on GPUs and it also heavily depends on minibatch-sizes.

Comment: There is no CUDA 8.1, currently.

Comment: sorry, you're right. I think I messed up cuda 8.0 and cudnn 5.1

Comment: As pointed out by sascha, performing computations on the GPU is not necessarily faster. Instead, this depends on the additional overhead of data conversion and transfer. For general measurement and improvement of GPU performance in MATLAB, see [this link](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/measure-and-improve-gpu-performance.html).

Comment: @Richard, I think you should make that as an answer

Comment: @Kaare it's posted as an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, performing computations on the GPU is not necessarily faster. Instead, the impact on performance depends on the additional overhead of data conversion and transfer.

Usually, the overhead can be influenced via the batch size, but the [trainAutoencoder](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainautoencoder.html) function does not provide that option.

For general measurement and improvement of GPU performance in MATLAB, see [this link](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/measure-and-improve-gpu-performance.html).